# How can I put click event inside a click event jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user click the first button, second button will show up,  And if the user click the second button, action will be called. How can I achieve this? appreciate.

```js
$('first_click').on('click',function(){
//second_click button show and some action here
 $('second_click').on('click',function(){
      alert('ok');
      });


});
```

Comment: The event handlers should be separated. You still want to have the second button action be called when you click only the second button, not when both are clicked at basically the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
'use strict'

$(function() { 
    var $button1 = $('#button1');
    var $button2 = $('#button2');

    $button2.hide();

    $button1.on('click', function() {
       $button1.hide();
       $button2.show();
    });

    $button2.on('click', function() {
        // your action...
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should turn visible\enabled the second button when clic the first.

```
$('#first_click').on('click',function(){
    $('#second_click').visible();
});
```

And then the code you want in the second button.

```
$('#second_click').on('click',function(){
        //code here
    });
```

The first button in html should be like:

Answer (score 0):

Attaching the actions to the buttons can be done anytime.  Simply show/hide the second button with the first:

```
$('#first_button').on('click', function() {
    $('#second_button').show();
});

$('#second_button').on('click', function() {
    do_action();
});
```

This assumes your second button is hidden by CSS to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are fun.

```
$a = $.Deffered();
$b = $.Deffered();

$('#a').click(function() {
     $('#b').show();        
     $a.resolve('data');
});

$('#b').click(function() {
     $b.resolve({"or":"something"});
});

$.when($a, $b).done(function(a, b) {
     //do something
     console.log(a);
     console.log(b);
});
```

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/